# Обновление данных в Entity Framework в случае их изменения на сервере MSSQL

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, entity-framework

Задачка следующая:

Есть БД MSSQL, к которой подключается около десятка клиентов. Связь с сервером в приложении реализована через Entity Framework 6. Каждый клиент должен определять изменения в базе данных на сервере в режиме реального времени и подтягивать актуальную информацию.

Например. На одном клиенте добавились или удалились данные, на всех остальных клиентах эти данные сразу же обновились.

Данные с БД в приложении планируется отображать в DataGrid WPF.

Может быть подскажете принцип, как проще это сделать. И хотелось бы понять, какой способ загрузки данных использовать (ленивую, прямую или явную).

Мои предположения: запускать таймер (с периодом 1 сек) на опрос БД -> загрузить данные с БД -> привязывать их к ItemSource DataGrid -> обновлять DataGrid. Но всё-же не хочется, чтобы при каждом опросе грузились заново все данные (да и это, мне кажется, глупо), а только те, которые были изменены. Не понимаю пока, как подойти к решению этого вопроса.

Может быть есть какой-то механизм, который может удаленно контролировать изменения в БД и включать какой-нибудь триггер или ещё что.

Comment: Клиенты должны подключаться не напрямую к БД, а к серверу. Сервер следит за поступлением новых данных и оповещает других клиентов. Например, используя SignalR.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, всё верно, под подключением к БД, подсознательно имелось ввиду подключение к серверу

Comment: Откройте для себя триггеры SQL... изучите, опробуйте на своём небольшом проекте, но лучше на практике не используйте и закройте для себя: слишком тормозно. Просто каждый клиент при вставке данных в БД должен не только вставить, но и уведомить о произошедшем изменении всех подписчиков, а это уже лучше делать при помощи SignalR как и рекомендовали выше.

Comment: @A K, спасибо за совет!